# Writing NDEF message to NFC tag with ACR122

Tags: c#, nfc, ndef

I'm really new to NFC technology and trying to get my head around it. I have a ACR122 and am trying to write a NDEF record to it.

I am using VS2012 and so far have the pcsc-sharp library installed as well as a NDEFLibrary I got from somewhere.

I can connect to the ACR122, I can create a NDEF message but then what? How do I actually write the NDEF message I create to the tag?

I can't see any functions in the pcsc-sharp library to pass the message to actually write the tag?

Can someone point me in the right direction? I admit that i'm a newbie when it comes to NFC and I still have a lot to learn, but i'm reading a lot and slowly getting there.

Comment: So 'what do you have' when you have connected to the ACR122?

Comment: You need to establish a P2P connection with the device (mobile in your case) and then PUSH the ndef record. Did you try using the libnfc packages?